# How to insert value cart codeigniter into database if has options

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

```
    $data = array(
        'id'            =>  $id_product,
        'qty'           =>  1,
        'price'         =>  '',
        'name'          =>  $name_group->name_product_groups.' '.$name_product->name_products,
        'options'       =>  array('player'=>$this->input->post('name'),'number'=>$this->input->post('number'),'size'=>$name_size->name_group.' '.$name_size->name_size,'comment'=>$this->input->post('comment')),
        'id_groups'     =>  $id_groups,
        'fabric'        =>  $name_fabric->name_fabrics,
        'option'        =>  $name_option,
        'order_type'    =>  'Order Uniform');
        $this->orders->insert_order_product_ready($data2);
```

can i ask, how to insert data on cart into database? because data has options

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want insert option in different table?

Comment: you are inserting $data2, the array you have defined is $data , and please share your db schema. Hope you can find a cure with modification of your db schema

Comment: If you need to enter the $data array you need to break the "options" element in to a string. The DB won't allow you to insert arrays in to it. Have a string delimiting your array values and use explode on retrieving. It's just one way. Or you can have another table carrying the "options" element's array values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i am solved by reading documentation, 
i use this to fix my problem
<?php $option = $this->cart->product_options($items['rowid']);  ?>
                                                    <strong>Player Name :</strong> <?php echo $option['player']; ?><br />